# Data or value retention of textarea and select input

Tags: javascript, php, html

When submitting a form via $_POST, the input file value remains. Like this:

```
    if($_POST){
    $error = false;
            if(!$post['price']){    
                $error = true;
                $error_note['price'] = "*Should not be empty";
            }    
    if($error == false){
    //submit/save the data
    }
}



 <form name="post" id="post" method="post"  action="">
             <input name="price" value="<?=$_POST['price']?>" class="text-input" type="text" maxlength="15">
            <select name="price-type"  class="text-input">
                                <option value="" selected>Select price type</option>
                                <option value="item">Item</option>
                                <option value="kilo">Kilo</option>
                                <option value="rate">Rate</option>
            </select>

           <textarea class="description" name="description" cols="55%" rows="6"></textarea>

        <button class="button" type="submit" name="submit-btn" >SUBMIT</button>
    </form>
```

But I have textarea and select input on my form.

**How to retain the content of textarea and selected item on select input?**
`value="<?=$_POST['price']?>"` doesn't work on it..

Comment: make value="isset($_POST['price']) ?  $_POST['price'] : '' "

Comment: <textarea class="description" name="description" cols="55%" rows="6"><?= isset($_POST['description']) ? $_POST['description'] : ''  ?></textarea>

Comment: check the 2nd comment for textarea.

Comment: @HasiburRahaman, That's what i am looking for! But how to do it on select option? You may post it as an answer.

Comment: Check answer for all fields .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this it may help you

```
 <form name="post" id="post" method="post"  action="">
     <input name="price" value="<?=isset($_POST['price']) ? $_POST['price'] : ''?>" class="text-input" type="text" maxlength="15">
     <select name="price-type"  class="text-input">
         <option <?= (isset($_POST['price-type']) && $_POST['price-type']=='') ? 'selected' : '' ?>  value="" >Select price type</option>
         <option <?= (isset($_POST['price-type']) && $_POST['price-type']=='item') ? 'selected' : '' ?> value="item">Item</option>
         <option <?= (isset($_POST['price-type']) && $_POST['price-type']=='kilo') ? 'selected' : '' ?> value="kilo">Kilo</option>
         <option <?= (isset($_POST['price-type']) && $_POST['price-type']=='rate') ? 'selected' : '' ?> value="rate">Rate</option>
     </select>
     <textarea class="description" name="description" cols="55%" rows="6"><?=isset($_POST['description']) ? $_POST['description'] : '' ?></textarea>
    <button class="button" type="submit" name="submit-btn" >SUBMIT</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: That was so easy to you! I just edit some of your code to meet my needs. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Is it possible as well to use this when my select option items was generated using jQuery?

Comment: Here is some part of it. https://jsfiddle.net/xkevin/a6hh4m5j/ This select option is part of my form above sample.

Answer (score 0):

You have used `short tag` but note that your short tag should also open for this

I suggest always use php tag

```
value="<?php echo $_POST['price']; ?>"
```

To set Short tag open do this

```
short_open_tag=On  //in php.ini
```

And `restart` your `Apache server.`

Comment: my short tag is working well on input text type. But not working on textarea and select input. And that was my problem not the `short tag`

Comment: this is not short_open_tag